# How to implement token authentication in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, token

I have built an application using Symfony 3. I have successfully implemented authentication using a log in form.

At the moment I am trying to implement a reset password functionality. I have a form where the user enters their email address. This will then send an email to them, containing a link to a page where they can enter a new password. On the page that allows the user to enter a new password, I want to authenticate the user on this page using token authentication.

My [ApiKeyAuthenticator](http://pastebin.com/T3hxfDiy) class, [ApiKeyUserProvider](http://pastebin.com/ZrUDwxwV) class and [security.yml](http://pastebin.com/aYBYmARJ) file. I added the following snippet in services.yml:

```
apikey_authenticator:
    class:     UrlBuilderBundle\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
    arguments: ["@security.http_utils"]
    public:    false

api_key_user_provider:
    class: UrlBuilderBundle\Security\ApiKeyUserProvider
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

I have the following routes for the forgot password functionality:

```
request_password:
    path:     /request-password
    defaults: { _controller: "UrlBuilderBundle:Security:requestResetPassword" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

reset_password:
    path:     /reset-password/{apikey}
    defaults: { _controller: "UrlBuilderBundle:Security:resetPassword" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
```

I have a token property in my user's entity class. When I browse to the reset-password page, I'm expecting to be authenticated using apikey from the request parameter, however nothing seems to happen - I am authenticated anonymously.

Sincerely appreciate if anyone can provide any guidance.

Comment: A system for password resetting should not authenticate the user but only allow him/her to reset the password. Then the login should be done again with the new password. Doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm, so how would I secure the reset password page?

Comment: Use a sufficient long and random unique id.

Comment: Ok, would I store this in the database whenever a reset password is requested?

Comment: Yes, you store this in the database, and then compare it... Anyway, I think I should better explain my thought: I think that a reset password form, should work the way I described: reset and then login again. This is because the user has to use immediately his new password: this guarantees (at least for this time) he remembers the new set password. But the use of a unique string to login is not bad at all: you may think at a system that logs in through a unique string. What I think is wrong is the automatic login after the password reset as the user MUST immediately use the new set password.